# AngularJS: Getting a List into custom directive is not working

Tags: angularjs

I am  creating a custom directive. Here, I am using an itemsList which is defined in the controller. This itemsList contains all the data I want to display on the page. 
This is my custom directive

```
directives.directive('studenttemplate', function($compile) {
     return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var htmlcontent = "";
                var studentItem = scope.itemsList;
                console.log("Inside the Directive", scope.items);

               for (var i = 0; i < studentItem; i++){
                        htmlcontent = htmlcontent
                            + "<tr>"                    
                    + "<td>"
                    + studentItem[i].name
                    + "</td>"   
                    + "<td>"
                    + studentItem[i].mobile
                    + "</td>"
                    + "<td>"
                    + studentItem[i].address
                    + "</td></tr>"
                }
            element.append(htmlcontent)
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
             }
        }
});
```

I am getting `undefined` at `scope.itemsList`. But when I use normal HTML code it is working fine. I don't know what is causing issue.

This is my controller code is

```
$scope.items = stuservice.getList(defaultUrl);
        $scope.items.then(function(data) {
            $scope.itemsList = data.list;
        });
```

Any help would appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where are you including your directive in HTML?

Comment: I am including it in my html page like this: <studenttemplate></studenttemplate>

Comment: From where does the scope.itemsList get its value? I mean any ajax calls to retrieve its value?

Comment: what it is looks like from controller in html ?

Comment: What is your goal with creating a custom directive? As pankajparkar mentions, you could just use ng-repeat to create a "for loop" in your HTML?

Comment: @Patrick  I am checking the page rendering time.  Present I am using ng-repeat it is taking lot of time to render the page. Here, I am using for loop to check the difference.

Comment: The reasons for a slow ng-repeat is usually due to a lot of data being rendered, and the fact that dirtychecking is used on all properties of the object. Have you tried to bind the value only once using `{{::property}}`?

Answer (score 0):

You probably are running an async call to get the data, while the directive is evaluated immediately. Try the following:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    // Watch the itemsList, then evaluate the directive
    scope.$watch('itemsList', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        var htmlcontent = "";
        var studentItem = newVal;
        console.log("Inside the Directive", newVal);

        for (var i = 0; i < studentItem; i++){
            htmlcontent = htmlcontent
                + "<tr>"                    
                + "<td>"
                + studentItem[i].name
                + "</td>"   
                + "<td>"
                + studentItem[i].mobile
                + "</td>"
                + "<td>"
                + studentItem[i].address
                + "</td></tr>"
        }
        element.append(htmlcontent)
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `itemsList` to your directive where the directive is defined in your markup and bind that property.

```
<studenttemplate items-list="itemsList"></studenttemplate>
```

```
directives.directive('studenttemplate', function($compile) {
 return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
             itemsList: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if(!angular.isArray(scope.itemsList)) {
                return;
            }
            console.log('studenttemplate got itemsList:', scope.itemsList);
        }
```

Comment: This is not true as in not necessary. He uses a `scope: true` which creates a child scope that inherits the scope of the controller

Comment: @devqon: strange causality. because it is not necessary doesn't make this solution false.

Comment: this code will run only once..what if you need to work when new record gets added?

Comment: @pankajparkar: I think your comment should move to the question as I excluded this problem in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create each row every time. `ng-repeat` will do the trick for you. Inside isolated scope will you need to pass the `itemsList` value of scope variable which you want from parent controller inside `item-list` attribute. The `=` sign indicates that `itemsList` object is two way binded with the controller.

**Markup**

```
<studenttemplate item-list="itemsList"></studenttemplate>
```

**Directive**

```
directives.directive('studenttemplate', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            itemsList: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("Inside the Directive", scope.itemsList);
            var htmlcontent = "<tr ng-repeat='item in itemsList'><td>item.name</td><td>item.mobile</td><td>item.address</td></tr>"
            element.append(htmlcontent)
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: nice copy&paste of my answer ;)

Comment: @angabriel  Its  not copy and paste..I was creating a directive with `ng-repeat` that took time..& I explained something more than you. :p ..Apart from that your code will run once only..not work for dynamic data..bdw what copy paste you saw excluding `scope: {
            itemsList: '='
        }` part ?

Comment: @pankajparkar I know ng-repeat will work. I have lot records. ng-repeat will cause performance issue.

Comment: @N123 lots of means..? then you need to go for pagination..showing lots of record on same page doesn't make sense from per UI perspective,,

Comment: @pankajparkar: we should not argue about it. I was just 50 secs earlier, the solutions are obvious anyway ;) (^^you also added the exact same markup)

Comment: @angabriel you want me to remove my answer..then I'll remove it..the main part was make it dynamic using `ng-repeat` you missed that one..should I remove my answer..then I'll remove it.

Comment: @pankajparkar: no, I like your answer. The OP should decide what helps him the best.

Comment: @angabriel Thanks :)  if you still have problem with my answer.then I'm ready to remove it..though it better or right..

Comment: @pankajparkar thanks. I know this solution already. But I want to get the list into directive.